# Omniauth: can't change response_type to "token" in Strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, oauth-2.0

I'm implementing a strategy to connect to an OAuth provider implemented using oauth-plugin. In the "request_phase" function, I wrote:

```
def request_phase
    options[:response_type] = 'token
    super
end
```

But in the HTTP request sent, it has "...&response_type=code"
I followed other examples to set response_type in request_phase as demonstrated for example with SalesForce strategy:
https://github.com/quintonwall/omniauth-rails3-forcedotcom/wiki/Build-Mobile-Apps-in-the-Cloud-with-Omniauth,-Httparty-and-Force.com

Please advise on how to change the response_type.

Thanks
Rami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified by the [OAuth 2.0 documentation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-20#section-4.1.1), `"code"` is the only valid value for the authorization code flow:

```
response_type
         REQUIRED.  Value MUST be set to "code".
```

You will then have to use the `auth_code` to make a second request for a token. It's possible the provider you're using only supports this method.

The flow that uses `token` as a response type is the [implicit grant](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-20#section-4.2) flow, which has rather different use cases and may not be supported by the provider you're trying to work with.